# Copy new data filled by Google Forms from one sheet in Google Sheets to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form that sends data to Google Sheets document, sheet "Form responses 1".
There are the following columns but I doubt it is important.: A Timestamp, B Name, C email.
When a new form is submitted I want results from a new row from sheet "Form responses 1" to be copied to sheet "Results".

My code is

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Results');
  var newRowValues = e.values;

  targetSheet.appendRow(newRowValues);
}
```

But it does not work. When a new row appears in the sheet 'Form responses 1' the sheet 'Results' is still empty.

Please tell how can I fix it.

Comment: Check your values output with `console.log(JSON.stringify(e.values))`. Side note: you won't need `sourceSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet0").appendRow(e.values);
}
```